# Getting Error: [$injector:modulerr] when adding angularjs.min.js - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I am adding

```
<script src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
```

in my html page, then I am getting this strange error

Error:-

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=letsendorse&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.5.0-rc.0%2F%24injector%2Fnomod%3Fp0%3Dletsendorse%0AP%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fdev.letsendorse.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A421%0Age%2F%3C%2F%3C%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fdev.letsendorse.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A24%3A99%0Ab%40http%3A%2F%2Fdev.letsendorse.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A23%3A149%0Age%2F%3C%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fdev.letsendorse.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A23%3A1%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Fdev.letsendorse.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A201%0An%40http%3A%2F%2Fdev.letsendorse.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A342%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Fdev.letsendorse.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A49%0Afb%40http%3A%2F%2Fdev.letsendorse.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A42%3A360%0Azc%2Fc%40http%3A%2F%2Fdev.letsendorse.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A421%0Azc%40http%3A%2F%2Fdev.letsendorse.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A20%3A225%0Abe%40http%3A%2F%2Fdev.letsendorse.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A41%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Fdev.letsendorse.com%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A303%3A112%0Ab.Callbacks%2Fc%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F1.9.1%2Fjquery.min.js%3A3%3A7852%0Ab.Callbacks%2Fp.fireWith%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F1.9.1%2Fjquery.min.js%3A3%3A8658%0A.ready%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F1.9.1%2Fjquery.min.js%3A3%3A3264%0AH%40https%3A%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fjquery%2F1.9.1%2Fjquery.min.js%3A3%3A693%0A
```

Here is my html -

```
<html ng-app="letsendorse">
  <head>
      <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div ng-controller="indexCtrl">
        abc
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please help

Comment: You need to also refer app.js/controller.js which has angular controller register in it

Comment: you shoud define module and controller and include it

Comment: I am also getting the same error when I am not adding any controller to html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without declaring module in js you are assing it in view

Try like this

```
<html ng-app="letsendorse">
  <head>
      <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script> 
        var app=angular.module("letsendorse",[]);
        app.controller("indexCtrl",function($scope){
        });
      </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div ng-controller="indexCtrl">
        abc
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```